# Ubuntu running "update-grub"

Tags: grub

When a Ubuntu update runs and it installs a new kernel, "update-grub" will run.  It finds and announces all of the Ubuntu systems currently connected to the computer, and even other Linux flavors and Windows.  I think it also has the potential to copy a new grub boot-loader to any of the systems it finds.

For instance, say you have a Ubuntu system on hard disk, and have also created a USB drive Ubuntu system.  You then boot to the USB drive and do an update where "update-grub" runs.  I say (think) "update-grub" will make a new copy of grub not only on the USB drive but also the hard drive.  If the Ubuntu systems are identical there is no problem.  But there are potential for problems:

1. Different versions of Ubuntu on USB and hard drive;
2. 32 bit light system on 1, and 64 bit on the other;
3. Same version, but the hard drive is a SSD drive with UEFI.

This can also happen when there is an existing system on the hard drive and you are generating a new system on a USB drive.  I've messed up several systems on USB drives and hard drives during system generation and Ubuntu updates (when it installs a new kernel), and I believe I have traced it to this, when `update-grub` runs.  When a new system is generated it asks you where to install the boot-loader, and even if you answer correctly, it can still copy to another drive when the generation links the kernel.

Is it possible to limit which drives that grub can/will be updated on?  To mitigate this I have gone as far as open the case of the computer and disconnect the hard drive temporarily.  But if it is one of the new SSD card drives, it is more difficult and I am not up to attempting this.

Has anybody else experienced this?  Am I doing anything wrong?  All I do is a normal Ubuntu update (just an update, not upgrade to new release) on a booted USB drive system with a hard drive, or booted to the hard drive with a USB drive attached that contains a Ubuntu system.  And then one or more of those systems will not boot again.

Comment: This is extremely weird and sounds quite unwarranted. I'm running Fedora and it only updates its own grub config file - it never touches any non-system disks. Actually recent Fedora releases don't even update its grub file once the system is installed - only new kernel releases get added via simple files under `/boot/loader/entries` - this is a lot safer than rewriting the entire config wantonly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is Ubuntu, from releases 16.04 up to 20.04.  You used the words "non-system disks".  I think that might mean "other than the disk you are booted to", but if not, then all of the ones I was talking about were bootable system disks, that had various releases of Ubuntu, 32 or 64 bit or both.  update-grub finds other types of systems too.  I don't know if it altered grub on them.  I wish Ubuntu did something like your Fedora does with new versions/installs of grub, but Ubuntu runs update-grub every time it installs a new Linux kernel, most likely 2 times a month.

Comment: In Ubuntu grub update only updates menu. Grub install will install grub to other drives, but not update that drive's menu, so could cause issue. I backup grub.cfg & turn off os-prober in /etc/default/grub. Then either copy a boot stanza to 40_custom or create my own that do not need updates with every kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Ah!  I see you've answered how my problem can be fixed before.  It seems clear, but I'll have to try it.  Thanks so much.  One question (for now), how do you turn it off for a new system installation?  The setting won't be set during the installation of Linux, and can't be set until after installing Linux.  So, if you have a good Linux installation on a hard drive, and are genning a new system on a USB drive, don't you run the risk of "os-prober & install grub" messing up the hard disk during that USB installation?

Comment: I do want to add the comment that what I feared would happen in my previous posts does happen.  The "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true" does not get added by default.  So, when you are generating a Ubuntu system on a USB drive where the system already has a Ubuntu system running on the hard drive, the generation process can/does overwrite grub files on the hard disk.  That is, you can't add the line until after the USB Ubuntu system is generated.  My system is a UEFI system, and there could be some interplay between the generated system and it that I am not aware of.